# Update Data With XML - xCelsius (SAP Dashboard Design)

Tags: excel, xml, dashboard, xcelsius

I'm using SAP Dashboard Design 6 and I need to update the .swf with XML data.

The main idea is to upload the .swf on a web server and get the data from a XML that will be updated sometimes. New rows will be added every update.

Something isn't working as expected. When I update the XML with new rows, these rows don't appear. I already checked the option to "refresh before components are loaded" on the Data Connection.

What I'm missing?

---

- Edit: I want to update only the xml. The .swf will not be re-uploaded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem.

We need to insert blank rows before the creation of the [.swf]. Thus, these new lines will be the limit of the new records that can be inserted into the [.xml].